# Fill SKShapeNode created from CGPath

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, fill, cgpath, skshapenode

I'm trying to create a custom SKShapeNode based on an array of points. 
The points form a closed shape and the shape ultimately needs to be filled.

This is what I've come up with so far, but for some reason the stroke draws fine but the shape stays empty. What did I miss?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    let center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()


    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, center.x, center.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x + 50, center.y + 50)

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, center.x + 50, center.y + 50)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x - 50, center.y + 50)

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, center.x - 50, center.y + 50)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x - 50, center.y - 50)

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, center.x - 50, center.y - 50)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x, center.y)

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    let shape = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    shape.strokeColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    shape.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    self.addChild(shape)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `path`. You typically call `CGPathMoveToPoint` to set the path’s starting point, followed by a series of `CGPathAdd*` calls to add line segments to the path. Try to create it like this:

```
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()         
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, center.x, center.y)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x + 50, center.y + 50)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x - 50, center.y + 50)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, center.x - 50, center.y - 50)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
```

Read [CGPath Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/) (search `CGPathMoveToPoint`) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For example you do not need use CGPath for this action, you can make somthing like this:

```
let points: [CGPoint] = [CGPointMake(center.x, center.y), ...] // All your points
var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextAddLines(context, points, UInt(points.count))
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(context)

let shape = SKShapeNode(path: CGContextCopyPath(context))
...
```